# Прокрутка блоков вертикально друг за другом

Tags: jquery

Есть два дива один над другим, нужно что бы они вертикально прокрутились плавно и нежно как в слайдерах. Код ниже в принципе рабочий, но коряв и при прокрутке образуется какой-то мега отступ.

```
$('#d1').hide("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
$('#d2').show("slide", {direction: "down"}, 1000);
```